# Get Data from the different collection without any relation in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

Get Data from the different collection without any relation in mongoose

Collection Schema

```
mongoose.Schema({
    skillid:{type:Number},
    name:{type:String},
});
```

Skill Collection

```
mongoose.Schema({
  userid: {type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId},
  OverView:{type:String},
  location:{type:String},
  skills:[{Type:Number}] 
});
```

```
 { 
_id: 5f48d5d1b98bffee67b49917
 skillid: 1
 name: 'HTML' 
}

{ 
_id: 5f48d612b98bffee67b49919
skillid: 2
 name: 'PHP' 
}


User Collection

{
  _id: 5f425bdb311b791670d60de6,
  userid: 5f41115fbd904134883ae2d8,
  OverView: 'sdsdssdsd',
  skills: [1,2],   // skill id
  Education: [ 5f453e7f53895727f0e39d82, 5f453fb963d4ab181c115982 ],
  location: 'India',
}
```

How can u get skill name from Skill Collection - mongoose

i want result like this

````
 { 
  _id: 5f425bdb311b791670d60de6, 
   userid: 5f41115fbd904134883ae2d8, 
   OverView: 'sdsdssdsd', 
   skills: ['HTML','PHP'], // skill id
   Education: [ 5f453e7f53895727f0e39d82, 5f453fb963d4ab181c115982 ],
   location: 'India'
 } ```
````

Comment: Your question is rather vague - can you clarify what you're trying to do/what the problem/error is? Adding your code would help...

Comment: i  have update question details please review it

Comment: Can you also add the schemas for your collections, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/index.html),

- [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) join `skill` collection, match skills in skill collection
- [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) to add skill name in array format using [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html)

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "skill",
      localField: "skills",
      foreignField: "skillid",
      as: "skills"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      skills: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$skills",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [["$$this.name"], "$$value"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ve4La8L5xxD)

---

Another option you can use mongoose [Virtual](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-virtual) and also look at [this](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3225)

```
// SKILL SCHEMA
const SkillSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    skillid:{type:Number},
    name:{type:String},
});

// USER SCHEMA
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userid: {type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId},
  OverView:{type:String},
  location:{type:String},
  skills:[{Type:Number}] 
});

// CREATES VIRTUAL CONNECTION WITH SKILL COLLECTION
UserSchema.virtual('skills', {
  ref: 'Skill', // The model to use
  localField: 'skills', // Find people where `localField`
  foreignField: 'skillid', // is equal to `foreignField`
  // If `justOne` is true, 'members' will be a single doc as opposed to
  // an array. `justOne` is false by default.
  justOne: false,
  // you can use other options
  // options: { sort: { name: -1 }, limit: 5 } 
});

// CREATE MODELS
const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
const Skill = mongoose.model('Skill', SkillSchema);

// QUERY TO FIND USERS AND POPULATE SKILLS
User.find({}).populate('skills').exec(function(error, user) {
  console.log(user);
});
```

> Note: please refer [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals), if you are getting any problem, This is not tested code!

Comment: I do not store _id .. Store custom field type integer like [1,2,3]

Comment: Thank You @turivishal -  this is cool, but can we do that with populate() function if possible!! because I have more than 3 table

Comment: i think populate is not supporting different field name, you can use virtual look at [this](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3225), you can add third collection also if you want look at [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/I242-mzUt6J)